# Why am I not able to use the keys() function of ActionController::Parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a project, and in my project some values get passed as query strings.

At any given moment, the `params` hash looks like this:

`{"ratings"=>{"R"=>"1", "G"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Refresh", "controller"=>"movies", "action"=>"index"}`

When I call `params[:ratings]`, everything works fine, and it returns `{"R"=>"1", "G"=>"1"}`.

I want to get the keys (R, G) from `params[:ratings]` using `keys()`, but when I call `params[:ratings].keys` I get a 'NoMethodError'.

The class of `params[:ratings]` is ActionController::Parameters, and `keys()` is one of it's functions, according to the API.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: [SS of NoMethodError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aW9QQ.png)

Comment: NoMethodError on what object? It's a nil:NilClass, isn't it?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, what do you mean by it's a nil:NilClass? By NoMethodError, I meant the red page that we get when running on localhost. I have attached a SS to the original post as an edit.

Comment: That answers your question, `params[:ratings]` is nil, and NilClass does not implement `keys`.

Comment: "At any given moment, the params hash looks like this:" - nope, it doesn't. Not on your screenshot, in any case.

Comment: @SebastianPalma, how is `params[:ratings]` nil? It contains `{"R"=>"1", "G"=>"1"}`, no? I am sorry, I don't understand how it's nil. Could you please explain?

Comment: Is that a GET request? Because there are no query parameters. Are you settings the params before the line 12? Check the value of params in the same REPL you get in the browser when raising an exception.

Comment: Ah! I understand now. I was so silly! I was hitting the URL which did not generate any query parameters. So silly of me. Thank you for helping me realise it @SebastianPalma